# How liquibase picks up hibernate transactions?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, liquibase

My `j2ee` application performs db transactions through hibernate. I want to integrate `liquibase` into my project.

I completed liquibase setup using the [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/07/source-control-your-database-with-liquibase.html).

I forced hibernate to be read only by setting `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `none`.

Now I run the server and perform `insert/update` operations. Hibernate doesn't save into database.

I am not understanding how `liquibase` picks up hibernate db transactions that was called before from configuration file specified in this [link](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki).

Am I missing some logic?

Comment: You are saying liquibase picks up hibernate db transactions that were called before you changed to liquibase? That does not make sense or I am not understanding what you are asking for... Hibernate transactions are used to make consistent changes to your db. Liquibase is about creating your database structure. Once the structure is setup liquibase is out of the game. When you run your server (with inserts and updates) liquibase does not have anything to do with it anymore...

Comment: Thanks Jens. I thought liquibase - hibernate plugin supports both DDL and DML. My mistake. Its only DDL.